# How do I create a Banner with more than six layers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

I'm playing on a 1.16.4 Minecraft realm on Java and I cannot make a banner that has more than six layers. Is there any way around this problem or is it hardcoded into the game?

Comment: In creative mode there is no limit on the number of layers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature hardcoded into the game, so the only way to do it in survival would be to mod the banner layer limit. However, if you have access to commands, I believe this website could help you out http://www.needcoolshoes.com/banner . Basically, the way it works is that if you input the layer's design and color, it'll add to a command that gets generated when you choose the type that suits your needs. When you generate it, just copy and paste it in-game and you're all good!

Comment: This is a good answer without the link, but whenever you link to an external resource, you **must** describe what the linked website is/does, and you must also justify why the linked website will be helpful to solve the asker's issue. Do that and your answer will be much better. Thanks!